# NSPredicate on Magicalrecord retrieves old results

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I dont know how this is happening, but I have a fairly complex NSPredicate:

```
NSString rentalStatus = @"Available";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(status != nil) AND (status == %@)", rentalStatus]
```

I then search with:

```
rentals = [RegisterSaleRental findAllSortedBy:@"rental_due_date" ascending:NO withPredicate:predicate];
```

Everything is fine, but if I quickly set a status from Available to Rented, the objects shows as Rented on the screen (so the status is set) but when I try to filter for Rented:

```
NSString rentalStatus = @"Rented";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(status != nil) AND (status == %@)", rentalStatus]
```

It doesnt show the object I just set to Rented :( If I filter for Available again it does show up, but the status I get in the object in the result it Rented, so it basically searches trough old data.

When I save core data with:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

It does, and works perfectly fine.
My question is do I have to save everytime before I change the status or anything? I cannot find anywhere that this is needed. Thanks!

Update (core data setup code)

```
// Configure MagicalRecord to use RestKit's Core Data stack
    [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
    [NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Are the changes made in a background context?

Comment: @MartinR the changes I made are in: managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext.

Source: (See question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probanly Magical Record do the fetch with Core data's fetch request. This request always goes down to the store. Therefore it only finds saved data in its saved state.

With Core Data's fetch request you can change this behavior by Setting includePendingChanges to YES. I think that Magical Record supports a similar Feature.

Comment: thanks man! I will try to find includePendingChanges for MagicalRecord. I will reply if it worked. + Give an example

Comment: I couldnt find a override for includePendingChanges for MagicalRecord but your answer made much sense, so I marked it as an valid asnwer. Thanks!

Comment: I changed to from my iPad to my MBA. So I can add a longer answer: I'm not experienced with MR, but it seems to be possible to get the request, modify it and then execute it: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Fetching.md#customizing-the-request Beside this, you should rarely need that: Every completed operation should be saved to the store immediately, esp. on iOS. While editing data, a fetch request shouldn't be neccessary.